# Retrieve numbers and strings of characters within quotation marks using regular expressions (regex)

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string of text in the format:

```
123 45 one two three four five six seven "eight" nine ten
```

I want to run a regex on this string to retrieve the values `123` , `45` and `eight`

So far, I have tried `^(\d+)\s(\d+)` which seems to get `123 45`, but I want those to be split and I also want to get the string `eight`.

What regular expression could I use to get these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the `"eight"` by capturing everything surrounded by `" "`:

```
/^(\d+)\s(\d+).*?"(.*?)"/
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty simple simple regex. Try this:

```
(\d+)|(\".+\")
```